# Is there any Implementation method for folder upload in gwt?

Tags: gwt, file-upload, directory

I want folder upload utility in gwt.
Currently I can use file upload like-

```
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
upload.setName("upload");
```

so, when the dialogue box appear (for selecting file) it doesnt select folder but open it,as it search for file.

Do we have any implementation or manipulation so that instead of opening the folder it will directly upload the folder ? or is there any folderUpload widget like fileupload widget or similar one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WebKit (Chrome, Safari), you can use:

```
upload.getElement().setPropertyBoolean("webkitdirectory", true);
```

There are currently no portable solution to uploading folders, other than asking the user to zip it first (and thus upload a single file), or relying on plugins (Flash, Java, Silverlight, etc.)